# Mounting partition on Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit

Tags: partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit,
but it couldn't detect my partitions(NTFS),
There is just "file system" partition(Ubuntu partition) in "computer".
What should I do now ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you installed a dual boot (and didn't wipe the disk), you can edit (with sudo) `/etc/fstab` file (`sudo nano /etc/fstab` in a terminal for example) and add something like:

```
#Entry for windows partition:
UUID=6AB40410B403DD87   /mnt/win7   ntfs-3g defaults,suid,dev,exec,locale=pt_BR.utf8
```

Where you replace `locale=xxxx` with your language (or don't use if English), `/mnt/win7` with the place you want to mount the windows partition (create the directory first) and `UUID=xxxxxx` with the UUID of your windows partition (you cand find it, with gparted -- install from software center -- or disk utility).

(obs: in fstab entry, be sure to use only one TAB or space to separate the columns)

After edit, use `sudo mount -a` or reboot the machine to make it appear in the place you mounted it.